# django - post_save signal import different app

Tags: python, django

I have a post_save signal which is creating an object in a separate model in another app which references a model in the current app and it's giving an import error.

Here's the signal

```
from passwordfolders.models import PasswordFolder


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_personal_list(instance=None, created=False):
    if created:
        PasswordFolder.objects.create(name='Personal',
                                      description='Personal Folder',
                                      owner=instance,
                                      personal=True,
                                      parent='')
```

here is the traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000004187158>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Projects\enterpass\api\core\models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from passwordfolders.models import PasswordFolder
  File "D:\Projects\enterpass\api\passwordfolders\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core.models import AccessLevel, Owner, User
ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessLevel'
```

The logic flow is it's a post_save on an BaseAbstractUser model in the `core` app which is calling `PasswordFolder` in the `passwordfolders` app which has an FK reference to `AccessLevel` in the `core` app.  It's failing when trying to reference the import on `AccessLevel` which is clearly there so I'm not sure why it's failing.

core.models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete, post_delete, pre_save, post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from uuid import uuid4

from .managers import UserManager
from passwordfolders.models import PasswordFolder


class AccessLevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_accesslevel'
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_personal_list(instance=None, created=False):
    if created:
        PasswordFolder.objects.create(name='Personal',
                                      description='Personal Folder',
                                      owner=instance,
                                      personal=True,
                                      parent='')


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True)
    is_support = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True)
    is_servicedesk = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True)
    is_infosec = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True)
    is_application = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=True)
    last_login = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_support

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_support

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_support

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
```

passwordfolders.models:

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import AccessLevel, Owner, User
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from uuid import uuid4


class PasswordFolder(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, null=False, blank=False, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    personal = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    class MPTTMEta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'enterpass_passwordfolder'
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PasswordFolderACL(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(PasswordFolder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    level = models.ForeignKey(AccessLevel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, unique=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'enterpass_passwordfolderacl'
        managed = True
```

Comment: post your models too

Comment: @Exprator updated with models.  My gut is telling me that it's accessing the post_save which is jumping to the other models file before loading in the initial AccessLevel.

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?? as with just 2 lines its not clear what the error is, so please post the full trace

Comment: updated with full traceback.

Comment: have you done migrations?? and when are you getting this error?

Comment: migrations are done.  when attempting to create a new user.

Comment: apologies.  wont even start with the signal code.  remove it and app works fine.

Comment: its more like a cyclic dependency error that is occurring, as you are importing models from from both files,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162139/discussion-between-whoisearth-and-exprator).